# Can I include category base in wordpress post permalink?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Is this possible, with resources as a category base?

category page - example.com/resources/technical-articles/automotive/

post page - example.com/resources/technical-articles/my-automotive-article

Right now the categories work, but the article returns a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that /technical-articles/ is a category, I don't see why not -- you can have posts that live in any level of subfolders. So /my-automotive-article/ would be a post within the /technical-articles/ category. The /automotive/ subcategory would not have any posts within it, assuming /my-automotive-article/ is your only post (but this subcategory certainly could have posts if you wanted it to).

If you have this setup and are still getting 404s, try saving your permalinks.